# Rails spec using Postgres test environment, test tables don't restart id increment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, database-cleaner

Just switched from from `sqlite` for testing to `pg`. I noticed that, while the test table clears out just fine, the IDs don't restart to 1. So in other words, given the test:

```
describe "" do
  before do
    # some dummy is created
    Object.create()
    puts "count = #{Object.count}"
    puts "last object_id = #{Object.id}"
  end
  ...
end
```

If you run many tests you'll get the following output:

```
count = 1
last object_id = 1
count = 1
last object_id = 2
count = 1
last object_id = 3
count = 1
last object_id = 4
```

Whereas I feel like it's better to both clear the test table and restart the ID so that it's:

```
count = 1
last object_id = 1
count = 1
last object_id = 1
count = 1
last object_id = 1
count = 1
last object_id = 1
```

I assume this is just something I need in my `spec_helper` file? For reference, current helper file below, and I'm using the `database_cleaner` gem. Thanks!

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Database cleaner set up below
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  # Clean up all jobs specs with truncation
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: Usually, the id of the object is irrelevant to the actual test, so resetting the auto increment should not be necessary.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the test using the truncation strategy? I'd expect something like `describe "", js:true` in the header of your test so I suspect you might be running the test with the transaction strategy instead. Can you show the test logs with the test running? There you should see clearly whether it does a transaction `ROLLBACK` or truncation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `psql` version probably below `8.4` that's why it is not working.
Find out your version with `psql --version`, and from the database cleaner source you need 8.4 or higher.

```
@restart_identity ||= db_version >=  80400 ? 'RESTART IDENTITY' : ''
```

I'm running 9.6.2, which works fine.

```
> truncate users restart identity;
> insert into users (x) values (1);
> select * from users ;

#  id | x 
# ----+---
#   1 | 1
```

To make sure, database cleaner works fine too.

```
require 'rails/all'
require 'database_cleaner'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('postgres://localhost/test1')
class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end
User.count
# => 1
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, reset_ids: true)
```

It resets the serial columns.

```
$ psql -d test1
> insert into users (x) values (1);
> select * from users ;

#  id | x 
# ----+---
#   1 | 1
```

Comment: nah... i just installed today so have the same version you do, will keep looking